# How to get form id in xpath expr odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo-10

I'm trying to get id or name of from view because I want to set it invisible
I try this

```
<xpath expr="//form[@name='res.partner.form']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
            </xpath>
<xpath expr="//form[@id='res_partner_form']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
            </xpath>
```

Comment: I think what you want is to hide a menu element, or change the action of the model in order to show only the tree view for example, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the name or id of the element to make it invisible. Just check for the element id/name in the html view (using inspect element) and then do the below in you xml view of that model.

```
<xpath expr="//form[@id='registration_form']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>      
</xpath>
```

Comment: I don't find this id/name in the html inspector. please some help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the menu that open that method
search for the id of the menu and remove the action
by default odoo hide menu that don't have action or child:

```xml
<record id="module_name.xml_id" model="ir.ui.menu">
    <field name="action" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

If not try to explain more what you mean by set it to invisible?!!